# Loading multiple layers into QGIS Batch processing

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, batch

I'm trying to process multiple layers with QGIS batch processing, but I'm unable to get all the layers loaded into the batch processing input layer(s) without clicking every layer by hand.

How do I do this automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are different options. Use the one that fits your needs:

**Add values by expression**

Use `Autofill... > Add values by expression` and define an expression that generates an array of strings that match the layer names you want to add. If you use e.g. the variable `@layers`, all layers of the project will be added.

From context help:

> Expected format: An array of values corresponding to each new row to
> add

**Calculate by expression**

Using the `Add values by expression` option, a new line will be created for each layer. This is the difference to `Calculate by expression...`, where only rows that already exist are filled up with a name generated by an expression. If you have e.g. 10 rows with no layer name (new, empty rows can be generated by hitting the green `+` icon), you could use `Calculate by expression...` with an expression like `'layer_'  ||  @row_number` and the row's input layer names will be filled like `layer_0`, `layer_1`, `layer_2` etc.

This is best if you have a fixed number of layers that have names following a regular pattern.

**Select from Open Layers**

Another option is to use `Autofill... > Select from Open Layers` - then you can check the layers you want to add from those you have open in your project.

[image]

Comment: For some reason I do not see the Select from Open Layers -option. Version 3.22.3

Comment: See screenshot in my edited answer.

Comment: Only the following options are available in my Input layer(s) Autofill... option:

Fill Down,
Calculate by Expression,
Add Values by Expression

Comment: You don't have `Add files by pattern...` etc.? Are you sure? If so, this is another problem, you should ask a new question for that - and add a screenshot showing the `Autofill...` menu.